# Capturing groups in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I wrote this regex:

```
String REGEX = "^\\s+something\\s+(not\\s+)?else\\s+((\\d+|\\d+-\\d+),\\s+)*(\\d+|\\d+-\\d+)$";
```

Here is my main method:

```
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(" something else 1, 3, 4, 5-7");
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      for (int index = 0; index <= matcher.groupCount(); index++) {
        System.out.println(index + ": " + matcher.group(index));
      }
    }
  }
```

and here is my output:

```
0:  match cos 1, 3, 4, 5-7
1: null
2: 4, 
3: 4
4: 5-7
```

It seems like `1` and `3` are not being captured. (The outputs `4` and `5-7` are fine.) How can I fix my regex so that I can capture them (and capture them without a comma at the end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to find numbers that are predicted by `something else` or `something not else` then maybe group them in one group, and then split with `,\\s+`, for example

```
String REGEX = "^\\s+something\\s+(not\\s+)?else\\s+((((\\d+|\\d+-\\d+),\\s+)*)(\\d+|\\d+-\\d+))$";
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(" something else 1, 3, 4, 5-7");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out
            .println(Arrays.toString(matcher.group(2).split(",\\s+")));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5-7]
```

Comment: For the record, the `((\\d+|\\d+-\\d+),\\s+)*` part matches `"1, "` on the first repeat, `"3, "` on the second repeat, then `"4, "` on the third and final repeat.